# Flutter: Firebase - The plugin cloud_firestore requires a higher Android SDK version

Tags: flutter, firebase

Flutter wants me to use the following code in my /android/app/build.gradle file:

```
android {                                                                                                  
    defaultConfig {                                                                                         
      minSdkVersion 19                                                                                       
    }                                                                                                        
}
```

But this code is already contained in the file:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 31

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 31
    }
}
```

How can I solve this issue?

Error log

```
PS C:\Coding\nutritious> flutter run
Using hardware rendering with device sdk gphone64 x86 64. If you notice graphics artifacts, consider enabling software rendering
with "--enable-software-rendering".
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
Building with Flutter multidex support enabled.
C:\Coding\nutritious\android\app\src\debug\AndroidManifest.xml Error:
        uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 16 cannot be smaller than version 19 declared in library [:cloud_firestore] C:\Coding\nutritious\build\cloud_firestore\intermediates\merged_manifest\debug\AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 16
        Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 16,
                or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 19,
                or use tools:overrideLibrary="io.flutter.plugins.firebase.firestore" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 16 cannot be smaller than version 19 declared in library [:cloud_firestore] C:\Coding\nutritious\build\cloud_firestore\intermediates\merged_manifest\debug\AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs 
not available in 16
        Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 16,
                or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 19,
                or use tools:overrideLibrary="io.flutter.plugins.firebase.firestore" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)
* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                              8,7s

┌─ Flutter Fix ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ The plugin cloud_firestore requires a higher Android SDK version.                                          │
│ Fix this issue by adding the following to the file C:\Coding\nutritious\android\app\build.gradle:          │
│ android {                                                                                                  │
│   defaultConfig {                                                                                          │
│     minSdkVersion 19                                                                                       │
│   }                                                                                                        │
│ }                                                                                                          │
│                                                                                                            │
│                                                                                                            │
│ Note that your app won't be available to users running Android SDKs below 19.                              │
│ Alternatively, try to find a version of this plugin that supports these lower versions of the Android SDK. │
│ For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-build-configuration   │
└────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Please increase minSdkVersion to a higher version, my recommendation would be 28.

Comment: I just changed it, am still getting the same error though :/

Comment: If you're using the latest cloud_firestore plugin please change `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` to 33 as well

Comment: Just changed both, unfortunaly still the same error

Comment: do you have the latest Android SDKs installed?

Comment: Just checked it. I have Android SDK 33 installed, there was an update though, installed the update, still the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` to 33, then try

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 33

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 33
    }
}
```

Make sure you are updating the `defaultConfig` if already exist, otherwise you can create block `defaultConfig`.

**Edited**

If you have two `defaultConfig` block, then make sure you merge both without missing `versionCode` and `versionName`.

As per the [discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252099/discussion-between-alex-sunder-singh-and-goku) made: If you already created an apk, then delete `\build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk` and `flutter create` to avoid vision incompatibility on build.

Comment: I just changed compileSdkVersion to 33, targetSdkVersion to 33 and minSdkVersion to 28, still getting the same error

Comment: Which version of `cloud_firestore` you have?

Comment: `cloud_firestore: ^4.4.3`

Comment: flutter version?

Comment: Flutter version is 3.3.10, channel stable, so it is not "that" old

Comment: Yeah, looks strange, Can you add full error log

Comment: I added the error log (at least what I think the error log is)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252099/discussion-between-alex-sunder-singh-and-goku).